# Can I identify the sqlite database used from an NSManagedObject

Tags: sqlite, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm working on a complex project that involves several different databases being accessed in the program.

If I'm at a breakpoint in XCode and have a reference to an `NSManagedObject`, is it possible to backtrack through the hierarchy of objects and identify which sqlite database this `NSManagedObject` came from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it... the database can be identified from the LLDB command line like this...

po `[[[theNSManagedObject managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores]`

And in many/most/all cases, the persistentStores returns only a single database, and that database will be the one the record came from.